# How to capture user level interactive events on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, analytics, android-event, user-tracking

There is Google Analytics, Firebase and loads of other analytic services which can capture the user events on mobile hardware and send it to an online dashboard. But AFAIK, none of these services log the events against each user i.e. although i will have a overview of user usage pattern of my app but when it comes to a particular user, I won't know for sure the events and clicks generated by him.

I understand this might be a bit of too much information for the services to handle and also might involve some rolling over some privacy fences.

But If i really feel compelled to record the events for a period of say 30 days, is there a suggested way to do it?
Is there any service in the wild that provides this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intercom](https://www.intercom.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=309846555&keyword=intercom&ad_collection=24444674115&ad=170132734071&match_type=e&network=g&ad_pos=1t1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=309846555&keyword=intercom&ad_collection=24444674115&ad=170132734071&match_type=e&network=g&ad_pos=1t1&gclid=CLqGgb_dvNQCFcwWaAodMQ4A1Q) service to achieve event tracking against the users'. But intercom is not a free service you need to pay for it to use it. You can try out the trail version and can verify how events are logged.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I think i need to make a payment to use the trial version.

Comment: My bad, actually Event logging is absolutely free. Awesome service and at first looks seems exactly what I was looking for. Some more digging due tomorrow. I will keep this as unanswered just in case somebody else comes up a with a better suggestion.